# Strange DWORD/QWORD C++ Strings in decompilation

Tags: c++, ghidra, strings

I have never seen something like this before but I assume this is some kind of way C++ allocates dynamic strings. In my decompilation listing in Ghidra I see something like:

```
  local_14 = DAT_00404004 ^ (uint)&stack0xfffffff0;
  local_70 = 0x2120302e;
  local_90 = 0x636c6557;
  uStack140 = 0x20656d6f;
  uStack136 = 0x45206f74;
  uStack132 = 0x7972636e;
  local_6c = 0xa20;
  local_80 = 0x6f697470;
  uStack124 = 0x694b206e;
  uStack120 = 0x76206172;
  uStack116 = 0x322e342e;
  local_6a = 0;
  local_28 = 0x203a656d;
  plea_str = 0x61656c50;
  uStack60 = 0x69206573;
  uStack56 = 0x7475706e;
  uStack52 = 0x756f7920;
  local_30 = 0x616e726573752072;
  local_24 = 0;
  local_60 = 0x656c500a;
  uStack92 = 0x20657361;
  uStack88 = 0x75706e69;
  uStack84 = 0x6f792074;
  local_48 = 0x3a64726f;
  local_50 = 0x7773736170207275;
  local_20 = 0x656d6f636c65570a;
  local_44 = 0x20;
  local_18 = 0x20;
  local_d0 = 0xa2e6e;
  local_f0 = 0x6f72570a;
  uStack236 = 0x7020676e;
  uStack232 = 0x77737361;
  uStack228 = 0x2e64726f;
  local_e0 = 0x656c5020;
  uStack220 = 0x20657361;
  uStack216 = 0x20797274;
  uStack212 = 0x69616761;
  your_str = 0x72756f59;
  uStack156 = 0x65737520;
  uStack152 = 0x6d616e72;
  uStack148 = 0x203a65;
  local_c0 = 0x72756f59;
  uStack188 = 0x73617020;
  uStack184 = 0x726f7773;
  uStack180 = 0x203a64;
  local_b0 = 0x766e490a;
  uStack172 = 0x64696c61;
  uStack168 = 0x6d616e20;
  uStack164 = 0xa2165;
```

I am not totally sure what `local_14` is doing either. But each of these locals is a string as you can tell from the bytes. Hovering over them gives the string (in reverse). I'd like to find a way to combine these in a way that makes them make more sense but despite my best efforts I cannot type them correct to get ghidra to recognize what they are and their relationship. What is the best way to handle these strings to clean up my decompilation?

Comment: `local_14` might be some sort of SEH or cookie handling. The others are probably a single `char[]` misinterpreted to many ints. Try to change the type of the lowest stack-address to an char array.

Comment: You need some experience for that, but most (if not all) of the individual octets of these values are within the ASCII printable range. Whenever I see this in IDA I try `R` to validate my assumption and then act accordingly. But with Ghidra I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard method for the C and C++ compilers to build static strings directly on the stack. This method will be used by the compiler when compiling this code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    char str1[] = "hello world from some string that is constructed directly on the stack";
    printf("%s\n", str1);                                                                  
    return 0;
}
```

Result in Ghidra:

```
undefined8 main(void)

{
    long in_FS_OFFSET;
    long local_58;
    undefined8 uStack80;
    undefined8 uStack72;
    undefined8 uStack64;
    undefined8 uStack56;
    undefined8 uStack48;
    undefined8 uStack40;
    undefined8 uStack32;
    undefined4 uStack24;
    undefined2 uStack20;
    undefined uStack18;
    long lStack16;
    
    lStack16 = *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28);
    local_58 = 0x6f77206f6c6c6568;
    uStack80 = 0x6d6f726620646c72;
    uStack72 = 0x747320656d6f7320;
    uStack64 = 0x61687420676e6972;
    uStack56 = 0x6e6f632073692074;
    uStack48 = 0x6465746375727473;
    uStack40 = 0x6c74636572696420;
    uStack32 = 0x656874206e6f2079;
    uStack24 = 0x61747320;
    uStack20 = 0x6b63;
    uStack18 = 0;
    puts((char *)&local_58);
    if (lStack16 != *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28)) {
                    // WARNING: Subroutine does not return
        __stack_chk_fail();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The only way I could find to make the output a little less noisy is to change the type of the variable that holds the beginning of each string to `char[N]` where N is the size of the string. In I've retyped the `local_58` variable to `char[71]` and I got this:

```
undefined8 main(void)

{
    long lVar1;
    long in_FS_OFFSET;
    char local_58 [71];
    
    lVar1 = *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28);
    local_58._0_8_ = 0x6f77206f6c6c6568;
    local_58._8_8_ = 0x6d6f726620646c72;
    local_58._16_8_ = 0x747320656d6f7320;
    local_58._24_8_ = 0x61687420676e6972;
    local_58._32_8_ = 0x6e6f632073692074;
    local_58._40_8_ = 0x6465746375727473;
    local_58._48_8_ = 0x6c74636572696420;
    local_58._56_8_ = 0x656874206e6f2079;
    local_58._64_4_ = 0x61747320;
    local_58._68_2_ = 0x6b63;
    local_58[70] = '\0';
    puts(local_58);
    if (lVar1 != *(long *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28)) {
                    // WARNING: Subroutine does not return
        __stack_chk_fail();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's still noisy, but at least now it uses just 1 variable for a string, and it's easier to rename the variables.